# Moving files when name is defined in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a strange issue. I am trying to move a file from location A to location B. When I hardcode the name of the 'Store_num', it works without issue. When I give it a filename from a textfile it errors out.

The error to me, looks like the formatting is getting messed up, but I am unsure why or where.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Value within text.txt = 4444

```
root = r"\\1.1.1.1\\ftproot"
rto = r"\\1.1.1.1\\ftproot\\AudioFiles\\HoursFiles"
Original_fName = input ("File Name: ")
Store_num = ""

def buildfile(root, rto, Original_fName, Store_num):
    copyfile (root + "\\" + Original_fName, rto + "\\" + Store_num + ".au")


with open('Test.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       Store_num = line
       buildfile(root, rto, Original_fName, Store_num)
       if 'str' in line:
          break
```

Error:

```
File Name: test.au
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\AAEasyButton.py", line 152, in <module>
    buildfile(root, rto, Original_fName, Store_num)
  File ".\AAEasyButton.py", line 136, in buildfile
    copyfile (root + "\\" + Original_fName, rto + "\\" + Store_num + ".au")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\1.1.1.1\\\\ftproot\\\\AudioFiles\\\\HoursFiles\\4444\n.au'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

note the filename in the error message: `4444\n.au`. There is a linefeed, before the ".au" extension and linefeeds are illegal in Windows filenames.

that's because when you read the file you forgot to `rstrip` the read line and linefeed got in the file name (iterating on a file line by line always add the line terminator at the end):

```
for line in f:
   Store_num = line.rstrip()
```

Aside: you're using raw prefix for your file paths, which is OK, but you don't have to double the slashes (except for the UNC prefix at the start). That's why the representation of your paths sometimes have *4* backslashes.

The clean way is:

```
rto = r"\\1.1.1.1\ftproot\AudioFiles\HoursFiles"
```

(you need 2 backslashes before server name/address: it's not escaping, it's UNC :)

then use `os.path.join`:

```
copyfile (os.path.join(root,Original_fName), os.path.join(rto,Store_num + ".au"))
```

Comment: Christ... that was it... totally missed that... I appreciate the help and will mark as solved after the timeout :)

Comment: In the raw string, do you need to escape all the backslashes?

Comment: no, but the first backslashes are UNC: you need 2 backslashes before the server name. Also if the string ends with backslash, you need to escape it (that's the only exception)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your file name has a `'\n'` character. This is an invalid file name.

After you fix that, be very careful about all of the backslashes. A string in code with backslashes must escape all the backslashes. However, when you read from a file, you don't need to escape them any more. Notice all the backslashes in the error message:

```
'\\\\1.1.1.1\\\\ftproot\\\\AudioFiles\\\\HoursFiles\\4444\n.au'
```

Since this is shown as a string literal, each `'\\'` represents a single backslash character. This means that you have read in the following from a file:

```
\\1.1.1.1\\ftproot\\AudioFiles\\HoursFiles
```

This is correct in your code, because the backslashes must be escaped. However, it is incorrect in a text file that you read into your program. Instead, edit the file to provide a valid path with a single backslash between each folder name.

Comment: that's not the issue. The issue is the linefeed at the end of the line, which is set at the end of the filename.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good point. I've edited my answer to include that. I'm sure after the OP fixes the new line character problem, they will get additional errors because of the erroneous backslashes.

Comment: not on windows. You can use a lot of backslashes that'll work (even if it's ugly)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So on windows you can put more than one backslash in between folder names?

Comment: POSIX open accepts that & also straight slashes. it can be problematic for MS-DOS-like commands (like the slashes). Pasting a double slash path in the explorer filepath/address fails, but it works in C, python, everywhere you can open a file. But the confusion about escaping the slashes and all is one of the reasons the OP missed the \n issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre TIL. I just tried `cd foo\\\\\\\bar` in CMD and it worked. /mind blown

Comment: try the same in the windows explorer address bar it's not going to work (or try `cd foo/bar` in CMD and it'll fail but will work in explorer!). Better stick to 1 backslash, windows design isn't so good :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Also, does Python's `open()` support this silliness?

Comment: `open` uses a Windows open system call in the end. This call accepts slashes, and double backslashes.